# Explanation asked about a Javascript / Angular line

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In a factory I construct a HTML page. This page can contain a form, so I want to get a handle on the `FormController`. After some Googling I've got everything working with this line of code (html is all the html in a string in a jquery selector):

`html.find("input").eq(0).controller('form');`

I understand that:

- find(): it is going to find all the input elements;
- eq(): I suppose this will select the first found item of the find list;
- controller(): this part is unclear. I find it hard to find some documentation about this. What I do know is that you can pass `ngModel` or `form`. When passing `ngModel` you get the `FormController` of the specified control, thus not the whole form. And when specifying `form` you get a reference to the whole form.

So, I understand the most of, but I still don't get if `controller()` is an Angular function or Jquery function and how/when you can use this method.

Comment: Its part of jQLite (angular) see [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Which if you have jQuery included, it could be considered the jQuery angular plugin

Comment: Why do you use this line, exactly? It seems to be a very bad one.

Comment: @Blackhole Well, I need a way to pass a FormController to a Factory. This factory generate some HTML and a new (child) scope. The HTML can contain a form and the HTML have some buttons. I want these buttons to be enabled based on the forms state.

Comment: Seems like you're doing DOM manipulation in a service, which is a **really** bad idea. Can't you use `ngView` for your problem, or a custom directive?

Comment: @Blackhole I know it is not ideal, but I don't know how to do it otherwise. In the factory I construct a modal popup. I can inject this factory and then use it like this: `popup = new PopUp({property1:'', property2: '', templateUrl: '/Customer/EditForm'})'.

Comment: Well, it's up to you to open a new question with more details, if you want :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of "controller" in jQuery: `controller()` is obviously an Angular function. [Here is the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> `controller(name)` - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with the `ngController` directive. If `name` is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this directive will be retrieved (e.g. `'ngModel'`).

Answer (score 1):

`controller()` is a method added by Angular to the jQuery object. It returns the Angular controller associated with the element. See the docs including other extra methods here...

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element